# Records insertion with primary key while load testing on locust

Tags: primary-key, locust

I have to test load on POST API on multiple users. API uses the primary constrains while inserting the records in tables. Locust will be facing issue with the primary constrains approach.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. What you mean by "primary constrains." Can you try explaining it again and include an example?

Comment: Some POST APIs start failing if the ‘primary key’ constraint is being violated. I need approach to modify the input payload dynamically, such that each API request uses a different value for primary key columns. e.g. -  suppose the "/save-user" API insert into the "user_table" which has column 'username' is PK. How locust will handle it when to not insert the same record while Hitting the API multiple time. @Solowalker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand exactly what you need still, but it sounds like you need each Locust user to use different data in POST requests you're doing. The easiest way would just be to generate the data randomly. It could be based on some sort of pattern, or if it has to be absolutely unique you could generate a UUID (or do a combination of the two like `locust-user-{time stamp}-{UUID}` so you can tell in your system back end or elsewhere that it's test data).

But Locust just runs whatever Python code you give it and automates running it concurrently. In most cases, if you write a simple Python script to do what you want successfully, you can just drop it into a Locust task and it should work. You can do whatever you need to in order to get unique or otherwise different data for your POST requests and have Locust users do that in your tests.